# Mapbox GL JS: Stacking order of features in layer – what determines it? Can you change it?

Tags: gis, mapbox-gl-js

I have a vector tile layer with about ~120 features ranging in size from over a million acres down to less than 20. I am having issues with mouseover whereby the large features are occluding the small ones, which are behind them.

I assume this has to do with the source data, which was sorted alphabetically by location name. As it happens, "Carson National Forest," which is big, is on top of "Valle Vidal" which is much smaller. So I can't select the latter with mouse interaction.

Is the solution to sort the features in ascending order by acreage and reimport the dataset, or is there something I can do within the Mapbox GL JS API to swap their positions?

Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem.

I'll assume that your polygons have an `area` attribute.

### Find the smallest polygon in mouseover

First, big polygons don't actually block small polygons from firing a "mouseover" event. The event is fired with all the features underneath the mouse. So you could intentionally select the smallest one.

```js
map.on('mouseover', e => {
   e.features.sort((a, b) => a.properties.area - b.properties.area);
   const smallestFeature = e.features[0];
});
```

This method also works if you *don't* have an area attribute - you could use Turf to calculate it dynamically, although it would be incorrect at tile boundaries.

### Use `fill-sort-key` to sort polygons

The other method is to use the `fill-sort-key` attribute in the layer definition:

```js
   layout: {
     'fill-sort-key': ['-', ['get', 'area']]
   }
```

Comment: This totally nailed it, thanks! Super helpful to know, and wondering why I couldn't find this in the documentation. I probably missed it or didn't know what area to look for it in. Many thanks. I used the second option – fill-sort-key on Shape_Area in the layer definition.